# android ORMLite get query Where NOT Equal

Tags: android, ormlite

in ORMLite document i can not find any document about this SQL command:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE state <> 1
```

i can get query where equal by this code:

```
List<ContactLists> contacts = G.CONTACTLISTSDAO.queryForEq("state","1");
```

how to change this code to NOT Equal

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> how to change this code to NOT Equal

The ORMLite DAO has a simple `queryForEq(...)` method.  If you look at the [code for `queryForEq(...)`](https://github.com/j256/ormlite-core/blob/master/src/main/java/com/j256/ormlite/dao/BaseDaoImpl.java#L248) you will see that it is just a convenience method for:

```
return queryBuilder().where().eq(fieldName, value).query();
```

This means that you can change the where to use `ne(...)` instead of `eq(...)`:

```
return queryBuilder().where().ne(fieldName, value).query();
```

To do more complex queries you should [RTFM about the `QueryBuilder`](http://ormlite.com/docs/query-builder).

The `QueryBuilder` uses the [`where()` method and `Where` class](http://ormlite.com/docs/where) to define the `WHERE` portions of the query.  There is `eq` for equals, `gt` for greater-than, `lt` for less-than, `ne` for not-equals, etc..  So, as @BrownKang points out, your query would be something like:

```
List<ContactLists> contacts =
    G.CONTACTLISTSDAO.queryBuilder().where().ne("state", "1").query();
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use "ne"

```
List<ContactLists> contacts =
    G.CONTACTLISTSDAO.queryBuilder().where().ne("state", "1").query();
```

Use like this.

Comment: i get this error:  `couldnot resolve method 'where()'`

Comment: I missed 'queryBuilder()'.